# ExoPlayer Restore State when Resumed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, exoplayer

I have implemented the Player and now there is a problem. When the video is playing and if the app is closed and resumed, the video screen freezes. I even saw the ExoPlayer Demo Activity from Google for better understanding but I could not get through it for implementing in my app. I have attached the Player Activity here and for the full code, I am sharing the GitHub repository for the complete set of files used.

RecipeStepDetailFragment.java

```
package com.example.android.recipe.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.android.recipe.R;
import com.example.android.recipe.pojo.Recipe;
import com.example.android.recipe.pojo.Step;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static com.example.android.recipe.ui.RecipeActivity.SELECTED_INDEX;
import static com.example.android.recipe.ui.RecipeActivity.SELECTED_RECIPES;
import static com.example.android.recipe.ui.RecipeActivity.SELECTED_STEPS;

public class RecipeStepDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    private ArrayList<Step> steps = new ArrayList<>();
    private int selectedIndex;
    private Handler mainHandler;
    ArrayList<Recipe> recipe;
    String recipeName;
    public RecipeStepDetailFragment() { }
    private ListItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(List<Step> allSteps,int Index,String recipeName);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView;
        mainHandler = new Handler();
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        itemClickListener =(RecipeDetailActivity)getActivity();
        recipe = new ArrayList<>();
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            steps = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_STEPS);
            selectedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_INDEX);
            recipeName = savedInstanceState.getString("Title");
        }
        else {
            steps =getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_STEPS);
            if (steps!=null) {
                steps =getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_STEPS);
                selectedIndex=getArguments().getInt(SELECTED_INDEX);
                recipeName=getArguments().getString("Title");
            }
            else {
                recipe =getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_RECIPES);
                steps=(ArrayList<Step>)recipe.get(0).getSteps();
                selectedIndex=0;
            }
        }
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_step_detail_fragment_body_part, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_step_detail_text);
        textView.setText(steps.get(selectedIndex).getDescription());
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
        String videoURL = steps.get(selectedIndex).getVideoURL();
        if (rootView.findViewWithTag("sw600dp-port-recipe_step_detail")!=null) {
           recipeName=((RecipeDetailActivity) getActivity()).recipeName;
           ((RecipeDetailActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(recipeName);
        }
        String imageUrl=steps.get(selectedIndex).getThumbnailURL();
        if (imageUrl!="") {
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl).buildUpon().build();
            ImageView thumbImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(builtUri).into(thumbImage);
        }
        if (!videoURL.isEmpty()) {
            initializePlayer(Uri.parse(steps.get(selectedIndex).getVideoURL()));
            if (rootView.findViewWithTag("sw600dp-land-recipe_step_detail")!=null) {
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container2).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH);
            }
            else if (isInLandscapeMode(getContext())){
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        else {
            player=null;
            simpleExoPlayerView.setForeground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_white_36dp));
            simpleExoPlayerView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        }
        Button mPrevStep = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.previousStep);
        Button mNextstep = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nextStep);

        mPrevStep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
            if (steps.get(selectedIndex).getId() > 0) {
                if (player!=null){
                    player.stop();
                }
                itemClickListener.onListItemClick(steps,steps.get(selectedIndex).getId() - 1,recipeName);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You already are in the First step of the recipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});

        mNextstep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
            int lastIndex = steps.size()-1;
            if (steps.get(selectedIndex).getId() < steps.get(lastIndex).getId()) {
                if (player!=null){
                    player.stop();
                }
                itemClickListener.onListItemClick(steps,steps.get(selectedIndex).getId() + 1,recipeName);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You already are in the Last step of the recipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initializePlayer(Uri mediaUri) {
        if (player == null) {
            TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
            DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(mainHandler, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
            LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), trackSelector, loadControl);
            simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
            String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "Baking App");
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), userAgent), new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle currentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(currentState);
        currentState.putParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_STEPS,steps);
        currentState.putInt(SELECTED_INDEX,selectedIndex);
        currentState.putString("Title",recipeName);
    }

    public boolean isInLandscapeMode( Context context ) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if (player!=null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (player!=null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (player!=null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player!=null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Complete Project Repository: https://github.com/mtp2697/Udacity-AndroidDeveloperNanodegree-BakingApp

Help with the restoring of the state of video player for onPause() and onResume()

Thanks,
Praveen Thirumurugan.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can store the player position on pause:

```
position = player.getCurrentPosition(); //then, save it on the bundle.
```

And then when you restore it, if it is there, you can do:

```
if (position != C.TIME_UNSET) player.seekTo(position);
```

before `prepare()` in the `initializePlayer()` method.

Ok, I cloned the project, and made it work. What I changed basically is:

**I added what I said before, and then:**

```
position = C.TIME_UNSET;
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    //...your code...
    position = savedInstanceState.getLong(SELECTED_POSITION, C.TIME_UNSET);
}
```

**I made the videoUri global**

```
videoUri = Uri.parse(steps.get(selectedIndex).getVideoURL());
```

**Added onResume:**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (videoUri != null)
        initializePlayer(videoUri);
}
```

**Updated onPause:**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player != null) {
        position = player.getCurrentPosition();
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

**And onSaveInstanceState:**

```
currentState.putLong(SELECTED_POSITION, position);
```

**Last**, I removed `onDetach` `onDestroyView` `onStop`.

Obviously this is "just to make it work", you will have to work more on it.

Comment: Hi Matias, the position is restored, but the video doesn't play and the play button also doesn't play. Only thing I can see is black screen with no content on resume.

Comment: How about: `player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false)`? you might have to store also the playerWindow for this (it can be accomplished with: `player.getCurrentWindowIndex()`). I will check your repo later.

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan I also don't see the play button in the code. Is the repository updated?

Comment: Hi Matias, I meant the play button in ExoPlayer (Play/Pause)

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan i think you are releasing player instance in pause instead of stopping it

Comment: Can someone help here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908685/exoplayer-save-and-restore-state-on-rotation-within-fragment

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old thread but, here is my fix

```
 protected void onPause() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    super.onResume();
}
```

this will pause the video on activity pause and resume on activity resume.